# Set visibility of a table row in HTML with C# codes?

Tags: c#, html

i want to show/hide a table row with using DateTime.Now.Month in html codes but i couldn't remember the correct syntax. What i mean is above, but not working in this way. What is the correct syntax? Thanks in advance

```
<tr style='<%# DateTime.Now.Month==11? "display:none": "display:inline"%>' ></tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asp tags come in a variety of flavors. The code you've written is correct but because you're using the wrong asp tags, nothing shows up.

This is the tag you want to use: 
`<%= %>` most useful for displaying single pieces of information

This is the tag you're currently using:
`<%# %>` Data Binding Expression Syntax
This doesn't work because you're not using data binding, you're just echoing a string.

More info here: http://forums.asp.net/p/1139381/1828702.aspx
and here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwsdcf5.aspx

Answer (score 3):

DateTime.Now.Year should probably be DateTime.Now.Month

Comment: Isn't it more a comment than an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `javascript` in `style tag` which is not executed. You can use javascript on body onload event or jquery document.ready event to execute your script.

You are using `2 digit year` and you would be getting `4 digit year`, you need to change 11 to 2011.

Using Javascript

```
<body onload="CallTrShowHIde();">
    <table>    
      <tr id="tr1"  onload='alert("ac")' ><td>hello123</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>

function CallTrShowHIde()
{
      var year = '<%= DateTime.Now.Year %>';
      if (year == 2012)
            document.getElementById('tr1').style.display="none";
        else
            document.getElementById('tr1').style.display = "inline";  
 }
```

Using jQuery.

```
<tr id="tr1">
     <td>Show or hide </td>
</tr>

 $(function () {
        var year = '<%= DateTime.Now.Year %>';
        if (year == 2012)
            $('#tr1').hide();
        else
            $('#tr1').hide();
 });
```

Comment: I have updated my answer with working code, I hope this would help.